# Practical example for recurrence relation of merge sort with more than 2 sublists

Tags: recurrence-relation, divide-and-conquer

I couldn't wrap my head around for finding an example for the following recurrence.

> $T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)$ where $a \neq b$ and $b > 1$

If we divide **n** elements with **b**, it should give us **a** sublists each with size **n/b**

Could somebody please give me a practical example of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "practical"? You could trivially make $a>b$ by repeating some recurrences. You won't be able to get $a<b$ because that would break the $n\log n$ lower bound if $f(n)=\Theta(n)$. Alternatively you could increase $f(n)$ to get $a<b$. Can you give a better description of "practical", because there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Consider any divide-and-conquer algorithm like Merge-sort. Let us say I have 12 elements which is **n**. Lets us say **b** is 4. Then we get 3 sublists each of size 4. But, as I said in the question, 4 is not $n/b$. Am I confused here?

Comment: An example of how to multiply two $n$-bit integers is [Karastuba's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Efficiency_analysis) which has recurrence relation $T(n) = 3T(n/2) + cn$. Another example is [Strassen's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) for matrix multiplication which has recurrence relation $T(n) = 7T(n/2) + \Theta(n^2)$.